# Unable to communicate with orderer from peer hyperledger fabric

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, kubernetes-helm

I am doing a setup of fabric using multinode environment with dynamic provision (dynamic pod allocation) over google cloud platform using native kubernetes engine.

I am using helm for the deployment . So let me tell you the entity which are running successfully .

1-> 1 Orderer with pod name `ord1-hlf-ord-54bbffd6f7-4qtxd`

2-> 1 couchdb with pod name `cdb-peer1-hlf-couchdb-7cf88678b8-74426`

3-> 1 peer with pod name `peer1-hlf-peer-6c5f6886d4-wrddj`

Till now everything is fine . Let me paste the results of some useful commands below

`kubectl get nodes`

```
master    Ready    master   138m   v1.14.1
worker1   Ready    <none>   135m   v1.14.1
```

`kubectl get ns`

```
default           Active   141m
kube-node-lease   Active   141m
kube-public       Active   141m
kube-system       Active   141m
orderers          Active   122m
peers             Active   122m
```

`kubectl get pods -n peers`

```
cdb-peer1-hlf-couchdb-7cf88678b8-74426   1/1     Running   0          114m
peer1-hlf-peer-6c5f6886d4-wrddj          1/1     Running   0          33m
```

`kubectl get pods -n orderers`

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ord1-hlf-ord-54bbffd6f7-4qtxd   1/1     Running   0          120m
```

`kubectl get svc -A`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes              ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  144m
kube-system   kube-dns                ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   144m
kube-system   tiller-deploy           ClusterIP   10.111.43.221    <none>        44134/TCP                138m
orderers      ord1-hlf-ord            ClusterIP   10.105.9.161     <none>        7050/TCP                 121m
peers         cdb-peer1-hlf-couchdb   ClusterIP   10.99.87.182     <none>        5984/TCP                 117m
peers         peer1-hlf-peer          ClusterIP   10.110.219.142   <none>        7051/TCP,7053/TCP        35m
```

now as you can see that orderer is running with service name `ord1-hlf-ord` so I am following the kubernetes pattern to connect this as `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local` so I am trying to connect orderer on `ord1-hlf-ord.orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050` In the below command :

```
kubectl exec -n peers $PEER_POD -- su -c "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/admin_msp peer channel create -o ord1-hlf-ord.orderers.svc.cluster.local:7050 -c mychannel -f /hl_config/channel/channel.tx"
```

But I am not able to connect to orderer

One more thing I want to tell you that when I am entering into the peer pod using command `kubectl exec -it peer1-hlf-peer-6c5f6886d4-wrddj bash -n peers` and trying to run `apt-get update` , So that by installing ping I can check that peer is able to ping orderer or not then I am getting error

```
root@peer1-hlf-peer-6c5f6886d4-wrddj:/# apt-get update
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease        
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                  
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done        
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If anyone faced this issue of having knowledge about the cause of issue then please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found one more clue in place of service name if i am applying cluster ip it's working .

Comment: Can you try to run 
`dig ord1-hlf-ord.orderers.svc.cluster.local` inside the container?
I suspect DNS probing issues.

Comment: yes something is wrong with coredns I think @ShaiKatz

Answer (score 1):

If it is working while applying the `orderer` IP address. Then probably try entering an entry for it in your `/etc/hosts` file. The entry will look like

```
    10.105.9.161 ord1-hlf-ord.orderers.svc.cluster.local
```

This should allow you to resolve DNS, you can check this by pinging `ord1-hlf-ord.orderers.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: this is not the solution . Need to find out the issue why kubernetes is not able to find the dns as documented .

Comment: so, when you tried to put an entry in hosts file, is it able to resolve the orderer domain name. @PankajCheema

Comment: I am sure it will work but I want to find the issue why service is not discoverable

Comment: If possible add googles name server `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the `resolv.conf`and check whether it is working that way.

Comment: Hmm, did you check in the GCP network policies. Anything there for DNS.

Comment: I think that should not affect kubernetes internal communication . There is already coredns running

Comment: Then I think the problem is in coredns. @PankajCheema